# android scroll view of linearlayouts

Tags: android, scrollviewer

I would like to ask if doing like this is possible on android:
Scrollview of layouts, and each layout in horizontal orientation contains button, another button, and a checkbox.

For example:

```
     button1, button2, checkbox
     button1, button2, checkbox
     .........
     button1, button2, checkbox
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using a `ListView` with a `SimpleAdapter`.

The `SimpleAdapter` allows you to specify a `layout` for each row in the `ListView`.

This [site](http://www.androidsnippets.org/snippets/58/) has a simple example.